# How can I replace a line with another line by its line number?

Tags: ruby

I have a file containing:

```
My name is Chris
My name is Chris
My name is Chris
```

Is there a file function to replace the nth line, in this case the second line in a file so the new file looks like this?

```
My name is Chris
My name is John
My name is Chris
```

I know I can read the file line by line, and write logic that says "if num_line = 2 then replace line" but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: "but I don't really want to do that" - why is that? Because this is what you'll have to do.

Answer (score 2):

What you're attempting to do is a bad idea. If the code crashes midstream, your source/target file will likely be corrupted.

Instead:

1. Create a new file.
2. Open the original file using `foreach`.
3. Read a line, checking to see if it should be changed. Change it if so.
4. Write the line to the new file.
5. Close the original file.
6. Close the new file.
7. Rename the original file to something safe.
8. Rename the new file to the original file's name.

Following those steps helps insure your original data is left untouched until the very last, steps #7 and #8, which then save the original file to a back-up and move the new file into the old file's filename.

Ruby's line-by-line IO using `foreach` is faster than if you tried to `read` or `readlines` so don't do that. In addition `read` and `readlines` aren't scalable. If the original file is huge, consider importing it into a database, and using the DBM to make the changes, then export the file back to disk. The utilities that accompany databases can load and export data extremely fast and *might* run faster than a pure Ruby based solution.

Your idea of replacing an individual line in the original file without creating another file is possible but the code to do so is quite messy. It's MUCH easier and safer to use line-IO and two files, which makes the process very straightforward.

Something like this untested code is the core of the process:

```
File.open('file.new', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach('file.old') do |li|
    li = 'foo' if $. == 10
    fo.puts li
  end
end
```

`$.` is a Ruby global that contains the line number of the last read line, making it easy to tell if that's the line you want to change.

Comment: But you have the last line right there, in `li`. Why bring the confusion (and, likely, a google session to find out what that obscure magic variable really contains)?

Comment: "If the code crashes midstream, your source/target file will likely be corrupted." - even if it doesn't crash, the file _will_ still be corrupted unless replacement line is exactly of the same length with the replaced one.

Comment: "But you have the last line right there, in li." Yes, but the OP wants a line-number based solution. Having the contents of the line won't help. "the file will still be corrupted unless replacement line is exactly of the same length " Only if trying to directly overwrite the original file. If the script crashes when reading and writing to separate files the original is intact and only the new one is affected. That's the whole point of the code sample.

Comment: I agree with all you said. I was just pointing out that if he were to operate on the source file directly, it almost certainly will result in a corrupted file, crashes or not.

Comment: "$. is a Ruby global that contains the line number" - ah, the line __number__. I read as "line content". Now you see my confusion? :)

Answer (score 0):

Let create such a file<sup>1</sup>:

```
s =<<_
My name is Chris
My name is Chris
My name is Chris
and other stuff
_

FName = "my_file"

IO.write(FName, s)
  #=> 67
```

If the file is not large, you can write:

```
lines = File.readlines(FName)
  #=> ["My name is Chris\n",
  #    "My name is Chris\n",
  #    "My name is Chris\n",
  #    "and other stuff\n"] 

lines[1].sub!(/\bChris\b/, "John")
  #=> "My name is John\n" 

File.rename(FName, "#{FName}.bak")

open(FName, 'w') { |f| lines.each { |line| f << line } }
  #=> ["My name is Chris\n", "My name is John\n", "My name is Chris\n",
  #    "and other stuff\n"]
```

Note that [open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open) is a method of the `Kernel` module.

Let's confirm:

```
puts IO.read(FName)
My name is Chris
My name is John
My name is Chris
and other stuff
```

<sup>1. The heredoc is not indented.</sup>